# Regex to match --private key -- including the positive lookahead before and after

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to write a regex to match this that starts with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and things that end with "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----" including the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----".

This is my attempt:

```
(?ms)(?=[-]+BEGIN PRIVATE KEY[-]+)(.*?)(?=[-]+END PRIVATE KEY[-]+)
```

Given this:

```
whatever
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
s1HQDfvgtTziGzwFxggjxYvfOw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
whatever
```

I want to get:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
s1HQDfvgtTziGzwFxggjxYvfOw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: As an aside: GitHub issue [#15136](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136) is a long-standing feature request that would simplify the solution to your goal to: `$String | Select-String -From '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' -To '-----END PRIVATE KEY----'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is almost fine, it can be simplified:

```bash
$string = @'
whatever
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
DANBgkqhkiG9w0BFQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEA
s1HQDfvgtTziGzwFxggjxYvfOw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
whatever
'@

[regex]::Match($string, '(?s)-+BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-+.*?-+END PRIVATE KEY-+').Value
```

Use `(?si)` for case insensitive. See https://regex101.com/r/LQME2Z.

If you wanted to find the string that must start with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` followed by a newline and it ends with a line starting with `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` and end of the line then it would make sense to include the `m` flag and use the pattern:

```bash
[regex]::Match($string, '(?sm)^-+BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-+\r?$.*?^-+END PRIVATE KEY-+\r?$').Value
```